# How to prevent rubber band bounce in an iframe on iOS mobile Safari?

Tags: html, ios, iframe, safari, mobile-safari

I'm able to scroll within an iframe on iOS Safari using the code below. Is there a way to prevent the iframe from bouncing horizontally to the right or left when scrolling? The iframe content is responsive. When I load the iframe content directly in a new tab, it does not bounce or rubber band.

```
<div style="height:900px;overflow:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch"><iframe></div>
```

[image: ios iframe scroll]

[image: ios iframe scroll]

Comment: Only happening on mobile safari?

Comment: That is the only browser we are testing with on iOS.